# Google & Facebook Login Controllers presenting modally in Xcode 11 iOS 13

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, ios13, xcode11, uimodalpresentationstyle

I have updated the pods to the latest version and

Overriden the method

```
override func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController,
                      animated flag: Bool,
                      completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
  viewControllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
  super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
}
```

All other controllers are presenting full screen but Google and Facebook Login are still presenting as page sheet.

How Do I present them full screen as earlier ?

[image: Facebook Login Screenshot]
[image: Google Login Screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

**Updated**

I found a workaround. If I set my LoginViewController as rootViewController of the window then they present full screen, but if I present them from a UINavigationController, then they present modally.

```
    func showSignUpScreen() {
      let controller:SignUpViewController =   UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController(storyboardName: .loginSignup, viewControllerIdetifier: "SignUpViewController") 
      self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false

      //Presents full Screen
      UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController = controller

      //Presents Modally
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: false)
}
```

But I can't always present as Tab Bar gets hidden when presented on window. I need tab bars to show other screens which don't require login.

[image: Tab Bar]
[image: Presented on window]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

following extension for showing safari view in full screen mode

```
import SafariServices

extension  SFSafariViewController {
    override open var modalPresentationStyle: UIModalPresentationStyle {
        get { return .fullScreen}
        set { super.modalPresentationStyle = newValue }
    }
}
```